# How to make a sound appear hourly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, time

so i made a clock using python3 and tkinter and it is not special so i wanted to add a sound when ever an hour passed i tried time.sleep and .after both didnt work here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from playsound import playsound


root = Tk()
root.title("Timer")


def one_hour_l8r():
    playsound('one hour later.mp3') #this is a file i downloaded it is the time card from sponge bob
    pass


def clock():
    hour = strftime("%I")
    mins = strftime("%M")
    secs = strftime("%S")
    day = strftime("%A")
    am_pm = strftime("%p")
    time.config(text=day + "|" + hour + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + " " + am_pm)

    time.after(60000 * 60, one_hour_l8r)
    time.after(1000, clock)


time = Label(root, text="", font=("Helivatica", 48), bg="black", fg="#00b9bc")
time.pack()

clock()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: any errors or something? or do u want idea on how to start with the sound

Comment: What if you run `time.after(10000, one_hour_l8r)` — does it get called in 10 seconds? What if you call `one_hour_l8r` directly — does it play a sound? Add a `print` call to it and see it it's even triggered.

Comment: when i use time.sleep then it calls and keeps calling the function and that proplem goes with tkinter after too

Comment: @CoolCloud i have an error where it loops the mp3 file and keeps playing it

Comment: oh okay, which `module` do u use to play the mp3

Comment: i use playsound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delay for the first call, then just recall the same method using a delay.

```
from tkinter import *
from playsound import playsound
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title("Timer")

def one_hour_l8r():
    playsound('one hour later.mp3') #this is a file i downloaded it is the time card from sponge bob
    time.after(60000 * 60, one_hour_l8r)  # wait one hour, then recall same function
    
def clock():
    d = datetime.now()
    hour = d.strftime("%I")
    mins = d.strftime("%M")
    secs = d.strftime("%S")
    day =  d.strftime("%A")
    am_pm = d.strftime("%p")
    time.config(text=day + "|" + hour + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + " " + am_pm)

    time.after(1000, clock)  # wait one second, update clock again
    
time = Label(root, text="", font=("Helivatica", 48), bg="black", fg="#00b9bc")
time.pack()

clock()  # start clock
time.after(60000 * 60, one_hour_l8r) # wait one hour then call sound function

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: but if i use that the clock wont work correctly the clock method is used to update time with ur answer the clock will be called once in an hour which make the clock increase only hours with no mins or secs , Thank u anyways @Mike67

Comment: Answer updated so clock and music are on separate timers

Comment: thanks so much u wont belive how many things have i tried tysm